# nosetests resuls xml ends up in wrong directory

Tags: python, nosetests

I'm running python unit tests using nosetests, and generating an xml report for use by something (Jenkins in this case).

Nosetests didn't appear to be publishing XML results, but after some investigating I realized it was just putting the file in the wrong directory.

Running

```
nosetests --with-xunit --where foo/bar
```

With nosetests **1.1.2**, this produces the file `nosetests.xml` in the current directory. However when using nosetests **1.3.0**, the file ends up in `foo/bar/nosetests.xml`.

Comment: I figured out this problem just as I was getting ready to ask SO, so I figured I'd answer it for self-reference and anyone else that has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason removing the `--where` did the trick for me:

```
nosetests --with-xunit foo/bar
```

This generates `nosetests.xml` in the expected (current) directory.